# How to update model joined with belongsTo?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a Consultation model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
   records: DS.hasMany('record', { async: true }),
   currentUser: DS.belongsTo('user'),
   remoteUser: DS.belongsTo('user'),
   created_time: DS.attr('number'),
   freeMsgCount: function () {
      return (this.get('remoteUser.msg_block')-this.get('user_msg_cnt'));
   }.property('user_msg_cnt'),
   .....
});
```

And User model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    .....
});
```

And I try to update User model. I get json data via WebSocket

```
socket.on('message', function (jsonObj) {
    if (jsonObj.action && jsonObj.action == 'userReload') {
         self.store.push('user',jsonObj.userData );
         return;
    }
}
```

But Consultation model doesn't know about this update, because I have property `freeMsgCount` in Consultation model which is using data from User model `this.get('remoteUser.msg_block')`. User data was updated I saw it in Ember inspector. How can I tell Consultation model to update relation remoteUser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're not watching `remoteUser` changes in your computed property, so it won't be triggered if `remoteUser` property's changed. Please add `remoteUser.msg_block` to computed property declaration:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
   # ...
   freeMsgCount: function () {
      return (this.get('remoteUser.msg_block')-this.get('user_msg_cnt'));
   }.property('user_msg_cnt', 'remoteUser.msg_block'),
```

Comment: Hm, I tried to add only `'remoteUser'` and it didn't work. Now I added `'remoteUser.msg_block'` and it works well.

Comment: AFAIK `remoteUser` would be only triggered if whole object would change.